# Failing to change bool var state in loop

Tags: python, if-statement, for-loop, range

I'm trying to write a prime number checker according to : [Prime equations](http://www.wikihow.com/Check-if-a-Number-Is-Prime)

My code so far looks like this:

```
def primer(x):

    prime = False
    x = math.sqrt(x)
    if type(x) == float:
        x = math.ceil(x)

    for i in range(3,x + 1):
        if (i % 2) == 1:
            prime == True
    print(prime)
```

Trying with 37 as `primer(37)` ---> sqrt(37) is 6.08

rounded to 7

7 mod 3 is = 1 ( Prime number )

I have no clue with that `prime` var is not updating. Could someone shed a light please ?

Edit : Linking some repl -> [Repl Link](https://repl.it/BJVu/1)

Comment: you could speed that up a little bit using `range(3,x + 1, 2)`; check odd numbers only - and check for even numbers seperately.

Comment: @hiroprotagonist will add ! Thanks

Comment: @Onilol, also, you can add `break` inside `if`.

Comment: Code is wrong. `i` will always be true

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are not actually assigning:

```
prime == True
```

Should be:

```
prime = True
```

`==` is a comparison operator, `=` is for assignment.

You can use the `any` function to create your prime number checker, also we only need to loop to the sqrt of x and check odd numbers. I also added an implementation of [fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) which is mentioned in the link:

```
def primer(x):
    if x == 2:
        return True
    if x % 2 == 0 or x < 3:
        return False
    return not any(x % i == 0 for i in range(3, int(x ** .5) + 1, 2))


from random import randint


def fermat_little_theorem(p, conf):
    """
     int p to test if prime
     conf is the confidence level/how many times to try n ** (p - 1) % p == 1
    returns with confidence p is prime based on 1/2^conf
    """
    if p <= 1:
        return False
    for _ in range(conf):
        n = randint(1, p - 1)
        if not n ** (p - 1) % p == 1:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: also you only print prime at the end of the for loop, so you will only see the value of the last iteration

Comment: Oh damn ! So damn blind ! Thanks !